# Convert a list of string to list of objects

Tags: java, string, list

What I have in a class is

```java
public void method(List<String> customerString) {
    List<Customer> customers = customerString.stream()
        .map(t -> new Customer())
        .toList();
}

record Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String amount) { }
```

The customerString looks like this : ["Jane,Doe,jane@doe.com,199", "Jane,Doe,jane@doe.com,2"]
What I would want is to make the input string list to a list of the object Customer. What I have tried so far looks like above. I am not sure how to give the populate the new list from the stream I get. It would be really helpful if someone can help to split the string the desired object

Comment: With something like this, you will help yourself if you give your `record` a custom ctor that takes CSV

Comment: Your main problem though, if you want to use `Stream`s, is that they don't really support partitioning. So you would be better off having each set customer of customer fields delimited, say by `'\t'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with parse a string into the `Customer` object. So you can use **regexp** e.g. Or you can just split the string into a parts with comma separates.

```java
public static List<Customer> parseCustomers(List<String> customerString) {
    return customerString.stream()
            .map(str -> {
                String[] parts = str.split(",");
                return new Customer(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

***P.S.** In this case, neither `firstName` not `lastName` nor `email` nor `amount` are allowed to contain `,` in it.*

Answer (score 1):

A possible strategy would be to parse your string in a secondary constructor of your record, e.g. like this:

```
public void method(List<String> customerString) {
   List<Customer> customers = customerString.stream()
     .map(t -> new Customer())
     .toList();
   }

 record Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String amount) {
    public Customer(String customerData) {
       String firstName = "" // Extract name from customerData
       String lastName = ""
       String email = ""
       String amount = ""
       Customer(firstName, lastName, email, amount)
   }
}
```

This keeps "method" readable and you can test your string parsing logic separately.